# click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, jquery-click-event

I have used live() to create a click event, on the table row, but the data in the table was getting cached, and then after some googling, I discovered that on() is the correct way to add an event to the selector.

```
$('#landingContactTable tbody tr').on("click", function(e) {
.
.
```

Table is showing 25 records, but has more records that can be viewed by clicking the "next" at the bottom of the table.
But when I go to next set of records, I cannot select on the table rows, the click event somehow seems not working on the second set or records.

When I was using live(), it was caching the data and I was able to select the rows on the second set of records, but then I need a way to remove the "click" event if the user clicks "rest"?

Please let me know how to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the way of using [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/),as:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

Thus, you should use:

```
$('#landingContactTable tbody').on("click", 'tr',function(e) {
```